# Circuitikz doesn't recognize units

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, units

For example when I use `\ohm` or `\micro` it throws an error. For example, in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) to [C=$100\ohm$](2,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

It produces the error:

```
"Undefined control sequence:    \pgfk@/tikz/circuitikz/bipole/label/name ...0\ohm :
(0,0) to [C=$100\ohm$](2,0)"
```

I updated the package and it didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to load `circuitikz` with the `siunitx` option.

Also, the correct syntax is `|component| = |value|<|unit|>`. The unit macro needs to be surrounded by `<` and `>`. The expression may not be put in math mode by surrounding it with `$`.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=1<\ohm>] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, as I wrote down, I would have preferred to use the simpler format as in http://pastebin.com/w8f4Pc9v without the '<>' is it obsolete?

Comment: That syntax was never officially supported, as I understand it. If you use ConTeXt, `circuitikz` defines a number of units and a mock `\SI` command so your document still compiles. The unit definitions are of the form `\def\ohm{\Omega}`, which then of course makes it possible to write `$100\ohm$` (in that case you need to have the `$` signs). You can find the list of definitions in the file `t-circuitikz.tex`, if you want to copy them into your document. However, I would recommend sticking with the official syntax: It's the same number of keystrokes, and `siunitx` is a very powerful package.

Comment: This is not proper use of the siunitx package.  Use `$\SI{1}{\ohm}$`.

Comment: @skvery: When loaded with the `siunitx` option, the `circuitikz` package provides a shorthand for entering numbers with units, so `\SI{1}{\ohm}` and `1<\ohm>` are equivalent here (but the latter is easier to type and read). See the [circuitikz manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf), section 4.9 "Integration with siunitx".

Comment: My bad.  If you include this in your answer I an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [the `siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) for the units:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) to [C=$\SI{100}{\ohm}$](2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that text in the following format: http://pastebin.com/w8f4Pc9v is now obsolete? it seems simpler than writing \SI{}{} every time

Comment: I would recommend you figure out how you want to handle units in general and use that method consistently thruout.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=${1\Omega}$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd advise againt using this method, as `${1\Omega}$` will give wrong spacing between the number and the unit. One way to improve this is by manually including the correct spacing `\,` with `${1\,\Omega}$`.