# Circuitikz: Electrical diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Below is what I have so far

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenx
% Euler for math | Palatino for rm | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}% rm
\linespread{1.05}% Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}% ss //  http://ctan.org/pkg/helvet
\usepackage{courier}% tt // http://ctan.org/pkg/courier
\usepackage{eulervm}  %  http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm
% a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)
\normalfont%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{textcomp}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 2]
  \draw                                    (1, 1.5)
        to[short]                          (2, 1.5)
        to[open, v^ = $y(t)$, o-o]         (2, 0)
        to[short]                          (1, 0);
  %
  \draw                                    (-2, 0)
        to[short]                          (1, 0)
        to[C, l_ = $C$, *-*]               (1, 1.5)
        to[L = $L$]                        (-1, 1.5)
        to[R = $R$]                        (-2, 1.5);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

I can't figure out how to add the `C = 1<\farad>` as well as for `R` and `L`.
Additionally, I don't know how to complete the circuit.  Below you will see the circuit I am trying to create.

[image]

---

**Edit 1:**

I have been able to complete the circuit diagram.

1. How do I switch the american voltage source `+` and `-`?
2. Also, how do I move `x(t)` to the left hand side?
3. <s>Can I move `L` and `R` so that they are above?</s>
   Apparently `L, l_` moves it above.  I don't know why since to me l should be left and underscore should mean below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenx
% Euler for math | Palatino for rm | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}% rm
\linespread{1.05}% Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}% ss //  http://ctan.org/pkg/helvet
\usepackage{courier}% tt // http://ctan.org/pkg/courier
\usepackage{eulervm}  %  http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm
% a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)
\normalfont%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{textcomp}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 2]
  \draw                                           (1, 1.5)
        to[short]                                 (2, 1.5)
        to[open, v^ = $y(t)$, *-*]                (2, 0)
        to[short]                                 (1, 0);
  %
  \draw                                           (-1.5, 0)
        to[short]                                 (1, 0)
        to[C, l_ = $C$]                           (1, 1.5)
        to[L = $L$]                               (-.5, 1.5)
        to[R = $R$]                               (-1.5, 1.5)
        to[american voltage source, v^ = $x(t)$]  (-1.5, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

So I added `\usepackage{siunitx}` but the below doesn't work

- `to[C, l_ = $C = \SI{1}{\farad}$]`
- `to[C, l_ = $C$= 1<\farad>]`

Comment: Have a look at 8th highly voted Q on [circuitikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz) for units http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31991/circuitikz-doesnt-recognize-units and for voltmeter symbol(sorry assuming) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42802/circuitikz-symbols-in-tikz-circuit-library

Comment: For a way of using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), see my answer. (I know it's not TIkZ but none the less.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I defined a new style for a component similar to `american voltage source`, but having the `+` and `-` inverted. This style is called `american voltage source inv`.
2. Instead of `v^= $x(t)$`, use `v_= $x(t)$`.
3. You've answered it yourself: `l_=<label>`.
4. Use an extra pair de braces to enclose the inner equal sign, as in `l_=${R=\SI{1}{\ohm}}`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenx
% Euler for math | Palatino for rm | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}% rm
\linespread{1.05}% Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}% ss //  http://ctan.org/pkg/helvet
\usepackage{courier}% tt // http://ctan.org/pkg/courier
\usepackage{eulervm}  %  http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm
% a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)
\normalfont%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{textcomp}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@circ@vsourceaminv@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{vsourceAMinv}{#1}}
\tikzset{american voltage source inv/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@vsourceaminv@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, v=#1}}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAMinv}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{

    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}


    \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{$-$}
    \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{$+$}

    \pgfusepath{draw}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 2]
  \draw                                           (1, 1.5)
        to[short]                                 (2, 1.5)
        to[open, v^ = $y(t)$, *-*]                (2, 0)
        to[short]                                 (1, 0);
  %
  \draw                                           (-1.5, 0)
        to[short]                                 (1, 0)
        to[C, l_ = ${C=\SI{1}{\farad}}$]                           (1, 1.5)
        to[L, l_= ${L=\SI{1}{\henry}}$]                               (-.5, 1.5)
        to[R ,l_=${R=\SI{1}{\ohm}}$]                               (-1.5, 1.5)
        to[american voltage source inv,v_= $x(t)$] (-1.5, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.05,-0.15)(8.1,3.65)
\psset{unit = 0.5}
  \pnodes(14,0){A}(9,0){B}(0,0){C}(0,3){D}(0,6){E}(4.5,6){F}(9,6){G}(14,6){H}
  \rput(16,0){$I$}
  \wire[arrows = *-](A)(C)
  \uput[0](A){$-$}
  \Ucc[labeloffset = 1.5](C)(E){$x(t)$}
  \rput(-0.7,2.3){$-$}
  \rput(-0.7,3.7){$+$}
  \resistor[dipolestyle = zigzag](E)(F){$R = \SI{1}{\ohm}$}
  \coil[labeloffset = 1](F)(G){$L = \SI{1}{\henry}$}
  \wire[arrows = *-](H)(G)
  \uput[0](H){$+$}
  \capacitor[labeloffset = -2](B)(G){$C = \SI{1}{\farad}$}
  \rput(14,3){$y(t)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) is used to draw the electrical diagram and [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) is used to typeset the physical quantities.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, I wanted to provide a very short solution to the figure that you originally wanted using circuitikz. Hence the code below. Plus the cute inductors that really make it good.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V,l=$x(t)$](0,2)
        to [R,l=R{=}$1\Omega$](2,2)
        (2,2) to [L,l=L{=}$1H$](5,2)
        (5,2) to [C,l=C{=}$1F$](5,0)
        (5,2) to [short,-o] (7,2) node[anchor=west] {+}
        (0,0) to [short,-o] (7,0) node[anchor=west] {-};
        \node at (7.5,1) {$y(t)$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This gives me this :-
[image: Circuit Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(10,6)
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(0,5){A}(3,5){B}(6,5){C}(6,0){D}(9,5){E}(9,0){F}
    \Ucc[labelInside=2,labeloffset=1](O)(A){$x(t)$}
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag](A)(B){$R=\SI{1}{\ohm}$}
    \coil[labeloffset=-.5](C)(B){$L=\SI{1}{\henry}$}
    \capacitor[labeloffset=-1.5](C)(D){$C=\SI{1}{\farad}$}
    %\tension[tensionstyle=pm](E)(F){$y(t)$} unavailable
    \uput[0](E){$+$}\uput[0](F){$-$}\pcline[linestyle=none](E)(F)\naput{$y(t)$}
    \psset{arrows=-*}\wire(C)(E)\wire(O)(F)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

Unfortunately `tensionstyle=pm` is not available for  `\tension` so we have to draw the tension with `\uput[0](E){$+$}\uput[0](F){$-$}\pcline[linestyle=none](E)(F)\naput{$y(t)$}`.

I don't know why my request (several decades ago in PSTricks mailing list) to provide `tensionstyle=pm` for `tension` was ignored.